# Array of JavaFX Pane objects?

Tags: java, javafx

I'm making Tetris in JavaFX and set up a the gameboard of 200 Panes set up in a 10x20 grid.
I have added all of those objects to my controller. However, I would like to set all of them up in an array so that it is easier to handle the coordinates. 
`Pane[][]` does not seem to be allowed, giving the error in Eclipse "Type mismatch: cannot convert from Pane to Pane[]" for some of the listed Pane object and "pane01 cannot be resolved to a type" for others. 
Can Pane objects simply not be put into an array? I could have sworn I was able to with ToggleButtons in a previous project, but I can't remember for sure.
Thanks ahead.

I set up the Panes in the controller similar to:

```
@FXML
private Pane pane00, pane10, pane20,
             pane01, pane11, pane21;
```

with the numbers representing the x/y coordinates.  And was trying to put them into an array as:

```
public Pane[][] gameBoard = {pane00, pane10, pane20},
                            {pane01, pane11, pane21};
```

I originally tried doing the above array setup just under the @FXML as the main setup of it in the controller, but it had the `"pane01 cannot be resolved to a type"` error on some of the objects (note: only SOME, others were fine for whatever reason)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add one more opening and closing braces to consider it 2d array

**solution:**

```
public Pane[][] gameBoard = {{pane00, pane10, pane20},
                             {pane01, pane11, pane21}};
```

Comment: If I could go crawl in a hole now and never be seen by the world again, that would be nice. Thank you very much

Comment: @fiveandten if you accpet this answer please check it